# Copy part of a sheet content to a new sheet based on conditional content in a merged cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to copy part of a sheet content to a new sheet based on conditional content in a merged cell.
If a merged cell content contains a text string, the lines that are defined by that merged cell will be copied to a new sheet.

It seems like the actual content of a merged cell is only set to the top cell and when I run the query, the cell below that (which are still part of the merged cell) are empty.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ghVneVl9PreUSsZPkIb5gdG5ZWh_TWztBqwPRFEXHsA/edit?usp=sharing

'Q2'!A2-3-4  is a merged cell with the text ' LT CLP'

when I query

=QUERY({'Q2'!A2:K},"select * where Col5 is not null and Col1 CONTAINS 'LT CLP'",0)

I get only the content of line 2 and NOT line 2,3 and 4.

the QUERY sees only Q2'!A2 as filled with the  LT CLP' text, while Q2'!A3 and Q2'!A4 are empty.

How do I copy all of the lines that are defined by the merged cell {'Q2'!A2-3-4} that has the ' LT CLP' text.

any ideas ?

Thanks for your help

Nadav

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you merge cells, you lose the data:

- the first cell of a merged range is value
- all other cells are empty strings `=""`

You have 2 options:

1. unmerge all cells and fill blanks
2. use a script.

In [[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), you'll find methods to cover your needs:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3");

 // True if any of the cells in A1:B3 is included in a merge.
 var isPartOfMerge = range.isPartOfMerge();
```

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range